# В чём смысл Interlocked.CompareExchange?

Tags: c#, .net, многопоточность

В документации есть метод: System.Threading.Interlocked.CompareExchange
Ссылка: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked.compareexchange?view=netcore-3.1
Судя по описанию - он выполняет сравнение с использованием механизма ссылок, вопрос зачем?
Скорее всего я понял не правильно, что в результате сравнения он подменяет ссылку.
Это такая хитрая система экономии ресурсов?

Если это не так - то что делает данный метод и зачем?
И вообще при чём здесь потоки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл `CompareExchange` в том, что комплекс операций сравнения и замены выполняется атомарно, другие потоки не могут вклиниться в этот процесс.

Дело в том, что при использовании последовательности операторов

```
if (a==b) 
    a = c;
```

в **многопоточном** окружении между сравнением и заменой другой поток может модифицировать значения `a, b` или `c`, и результат будет непредсказуем.

Comment: того же самого можно добиться обернув конструкцию в lock или мьютекс/семафор, но это очень ресурсоемкие конструкции, в отличие от методов класса Interlocked

Comment: @MBo доп вопрос: а если CompareExchange выполняется на одном ядре процессора, а одна из переменный меняется в другом? Просто многоядерность, насколько мне известно, более сложная тема, чем многопоточность.

Comment: На многопроцессорных системах используется LOCK инструкция, обеспечивающая монопольный доступ к шине данных `In the x86 (since 80486) and Itanium architectures this is implemented as the compare and exchange (CMPXCHG) instruction (on a multiprocessor the LOCK prefix must be used).` И `most multiprocessor architectures support CAS in hardware` (CompareAndExchange)

Comment: В книге Соломона об внутреннем устройстве Windows таких подробностей, кажется, нет (там много внимания планированию выполнения потоков, а не синхронизации уделено).  Таненбаума  (Операционные системы) бегло просмотрел - тоже не увидел.

Answer (score 2):

[Сравнение с обменом](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC) - атомарная операция, используемая для реализации [неблокирующих](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%85%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F) (lock-free) алгоритмов.

Такие алгоритмы во многих случаях (не всегда!) оказываются предпочтительней, чем реализации с блокировками.

Некоторые [потокобезопасные коллекции](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/) в современном дотнете используют внутри себя такие операции.